# Strange alignment of scaled greek letters in fractions (XeTeX or pdfTeX)

Tags: horizontal-alignment

The following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,multirow,mathptmx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
$$\frac{\scalebox{0.7}[0.7]{$\mu$}}{2\lambda x}$$
\end{document}
```

typesets to:

[image]

Apart from the odd scaling, which is the wrong factor and looks better with 0.9, why is that mu not centered in the fraction but moved to the right side? PS All I can do to avoid this is `\mathclap`ing the letter with the `mathtools` package, or maybe putting a negative space before it, as far as I know...

Comment: Why should you want to scale `\mu` in the first place?

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,multirow,mathptmx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\[\frac{\scalebox{0.7}[0.7]{$\mu$}}{2\lambda x}\]
\[\frac{\mu}{2\lambda x}\]
\[\frac{\scriptscriptstyle\mu}{2\lambda x}\]
\end{document}
```

By putting it in a box you started a new math context (which is why it is full size) and hid the font metric information so it loses the italic correction, which is why it is shifted.

(I'm not sure of the intent of the scaling, perhaps you want `\scriptstyle`)

Comment: @egreg the scaling is to fit it in better when mixing greek and latin, since greek letters are naturally slightly taller than latin letters. Then it gets lone in fractions to keep a uniform letter size. @David Carlisle `\scriptstyle` might be fine in subscripts and superscripts, but in a fraction it's too small. In fact I said in the question that the scale factor was probably too little.

Comment: The right factor would be about 0.85 in "normal" size and 0.65 in superscripts and similar.